# Serilog timeouts exceptions

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I am getting this message in the serilog SelfLog file:

> 2022-03-23T12:32:38.2659227Z The property accessor Int32 ReadTimeout threw exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
> at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
> at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.GetProperties(Object value)+MoveNext()

> 2022-03-23T12:32:38.2672682Z The property accessor Int32 WriteTimeout threw exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.
> at System.IO.Stream.get_WriteTimeout()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
> at Serilog.Capturing.PropertyValueConverter.GetProperties(Object value)+MoveNext()

It's been working fine for 3 years until now. Mi project is .NET Core 3.1 and Serilog.AspNetCore 5.0.0.

How can I get more detail of the exception?

Comment: The above suggests that you are logging something that has a Stream in it, perhaps with an `{@value}` tag - you can either stop doing that (including and triggering capturing of such fields), or you can change the config wiring to ignore a given type. You should be able to run under the debugger and get it to stop on exceptions to determine which log statement is triggering this if the stack trace is insufficient to guide you to that